# How to reset value of a column by sequential values start by 1 with where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table, which include 3 columns:

> id, priority, dict_id

For each dict_id, it has maximum 1000 priority, start from 1 (sequential).
When I delete some priority, how to make the value of priority column sequential (not use trigger).
For example:
The original data

```
id, priority, dict_id
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
3, 3, 1
4, 4, 1
5, 5, 1
6, 6, 1
```

After delete id 3 and 5, the data of table:

```
id, priority, dict_id
1, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
4, 4, 1
6, 6, 1
```

I want the priority column like this

```
    id, priority, dict_id
    1, 1, 1
    2, 2, 1
    4, 3, 1
    6, 4, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an `UPDATE FROM` syntax

```
UPDATE yourtab a 
SET    priority = s.priority 
FROM   (SELECT id, 
               row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   ORDER BY id) priority 
        FROM   yourtab) s 
WHERE  a.id = s.id;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/12039/1)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend doing this, because the `priority` column with the ordering you want can easily be generated at the time you query using `ROW_NUMBER`, e.g.

```
SELECT
    id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) priority,
    dict_id
FROM your_table;
```

You might want to avoid paying a frequent DML penalty everytime you add/remove records from your table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I want to update the data in database, not just display in the result

Comment: The update command you would run would probably also involve row number.  But, that wouldn't be much first choice of what to do.